# Iteration through dictionaries, Firebase snapshot using

Tags: firebase, for-loop, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem while iterating through a dictionary. First check my database[image: database]

And here is my code

```
ref.child("Events").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children{

        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot

        let valueSnap = snap.value as? [[String:Any]]
        let nombreEventDansClub = valueSnap?.count
        print(valueSnap)
        for index in 0...nombreEventDansClub!-1
        {
            print(valueSnap![index]["name"])
            //print(valueSnap![index]["end_time"])
            if(valueSnap![index]["end_time"] as? String == nil)
            {
                //do Something
            }
            else{
            let end_time_test = valueSnap![index]["end_time"] as? String
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+2:00")
            let end_test = dateFormatter.date(from: end_time_test!)!
```

The recuperation is perfect but for example : if Event-0-(3) didn't exist the app would crash, I know the problem is that I calculate the number of events in a : Event-(something) and iterate according to this. I was wondering if there is a smarter way. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the snapshot this way:-

```
   ref.child("Events").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    guard let values = snapshot as? [Any] else { return }
    for value in values {
        guard let childrens = value as? [Any] else { continue }
        for children in childrens {
            guard let dict = children as? [String: Any] else { continue }
            for key in dict.allkeys {

                // TO debug all keys and values
                print(dict[key])
            }

            print(dict["description"] as? String)
            print(dict["end_time"] as? String)
            print(dict["id"] as? String)
            // other keys
        }
    }
}
```

Force unwrapping may cause your app crash unexpectedly.